# How to reterieve data from a SharePoint List by using REST URL?

Tags: list

First, please assuming that my company domain name is www.aaa.com, and I am trying to reterieve a list data from the SharePoint list REST endpoint. The list that I am trying to access is used in the following webpage: http://www.aaa.com/tpn/toolcenter/esri/Pages/Portal/Portal.aspx. And I can get the list names with: http://www.aaa.com/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/, and I think the list name that I am looking for is called "Pages".

Then I am trying to compose the Odata REST url to get the list data from browser but failed. The url that I tried is: http://www.aaa.com/sites/_api/lists/GetByTitle('Pages')

The error messsage that I get is http 404. Could anyone please let me know what might be wrong for my Odata Url?

Appreciate your help very much!

Comment: are you using SharePoint 2010 ? If not, which version?

Answer (score 0):

Since your pages exist under http://www.aaa.com/tpn/toolcenter/esri use:

http://www.aaa.com/tpn/toolcenter/esri/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Pages')

Answer (score 0):

url:_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl+"/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('YourListName')/items

But According to me for checking purpose you have to give your site name hard coded in url.

"_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl" this will take name of your site dynamically.